# Compare two maps for keys and return boolean

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have two maps and I need to check if both has the same keys and same number of keys or not and return a boolean. I would like to use streams for this and I have got is by creating another list

```
mapA
.entrySet()
.stream()
.filter(entry -> mapB.containsKey(entry.getKey()))
.collect(
    Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
```

But my question is that can I do it in a single line that would not create another list but return a boolean whether if they are same or not.

Comment: You mean true when such entries exist?

Comment: @Andronicus Yes if both maps have same keys and same number of keys then i need to return true else false

Comment: @YCF_L Thanks I would need to check if the number of keys is also same in both the maps

Comment: @YCF_L If mapA has additional keys that mapB doesn't have, containsAll will still return true.  That's not what OP wants.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need to use streams for this.  Just obtain the maps' key sets and use [`equals`, which is specified in `Set` as follows](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#equals(java.lang.Object)):

> Returns `true` if the specified object is also a set, the two sets have the same size, and every member of the specified set is contained in this set [.]

```
Map<String, Integer> m1 = new HashMap<>();
m1.put("a", 10);
m1.put("b", 10);
m1.put("c", 10);

Map<String, Integer> m2 = new HashMap<>();
m2.put("c", 20);
m2.put("b", 20);
m2.put("a", 20);

System.out.println(m1.keySet().equals(m2.keySet()));  //true
```